# bigvideo.js in rails routing error?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

So I have a video background I want to include in my rails app. Below is the html that works perfectly outside of rails where the required files are all in a folder titled js.

This does not work in Rails however. According to the server I have the following error:

```
Started GET "/js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-15 12:46:02 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>VideoRail</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<p>bubblers!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
    <!-- BigVideo Dependencies -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>

    <!-- BigVideo -->
    <script src="js/bigvideo.js"></script>

    <!-- Demo -->
    <script>
      $(function() {
            var BV = new $.BigVideo();
      BV.init();
            BV.show('blue.mov');
      });
    </script>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate it can't find the library, try using an asset tag helper to load your jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js file

```
<%= javascript_include_tag("jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js") %>
```

Assuming that jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js library is in app/assets/javascripts or lib/assets/javascripts or vendor/assets/javascripts

For more information about the javascript_include_tag check out the [Asset Tag Helpers in Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#asset-tag-helpers) or the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag)